# IBM MFP8 Respnse after Security Check

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MFP8 in my app. I am using security check framework to validate user. To validate user i am using some backend layer to validate user. Once user authenticated my backend service will return huge JSON. Now I need to send this response to client.

PFB the code I have tried in UserLogin adapter. What ever the response coming from my backend layer is very huge response (75-80KB) in JSON format. Please help how to send this response to client from security check

P.S :

```
public class UserLoginResource extends UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck {
    private String userId, displayName,errorMsg, cdata, hdata, rid, urlParams, serviceName, queryParameters;   
    private boolean rememberMe = false;
    private boolean authFlag=true;  
    public static JSONObject queryResponse;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @Context
    AdapterSecurityContext adapterSecurityContext;

    @Override
    protected AuthenticatedUser createUser() {       
        System.out.println("User Authenticated Result "+ userId);        
        return new AuthenticatedUser(userId, displayName, this.getName(), attributes);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validateCredentials(Map<String, Object> credentials) {

        try{            
            String username=credentials.get("username").toString();     
            String password = credentials.get("password").toString();    ;

            if (username != null && password != null) {

                queryResponse = <my backend layer>(username, password);

                if(queryResponse.errorExist){                       
                    System.out.println("User Authentication Failed");
                    errorMsg="User Authentication Failed";
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("User Authentication Sucessful");
                    userId=queryResponse.userid;
                    displayName=queryResponse.fullname;

                    attributes.put("queryParams", queryResponse.toString());                        
                    authFlag=false;
                    errorMsg = null;
                    return true;
                }
            }           
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            authFlag =true;
            return false;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you re-design your authentication flow.

SecurityCheck adapters are designed to do exactly what the name suggests - security check. Ideally, `validateCredentials`method should validate your credentials ( against a backend/LDAP/service or other means) and the response from your Security Check should be the information about the authenticated identity and custom attributes you might need.

Note that, Security checks are stateful and retains its interaction state. On each authorization or introspection request, the security framework retrieves the states of relevant security checks from external storage and at the end of request processing, stores the security-check states back in external storage. With the approach you are asking, the response also becomes part of the state and incurs performance penalties with the serialization and deserialization. This is not suited for a heavily loaded system.

Refer to [Security-check state management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_security_check_contract.html).

You should ideally be deferring the JSON request and response to a resource adapter that will request it, post authentication using your Security Check.

If you really really want to keep the model you have now, you should mark your custom JSON response as `transient` to prevent its serialization (and becoming part of the SecurityCheck state) and send the data back in the custom Map that is part of your AuthenticatedUser constructor you are already using:

> AuthenticatedUser(String id, String displayName, String
>   securityCheckName, Map attributes);

```
return new AuthenticatedUser(userId, displayName, this.getName(), attributes);
```